# Should all links to meta.* be "nofollow"

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, subdomains, nofollow

Does the community want meta.* to be listed on Google and other search engines?

Surely it would be confusing to noobs - they would find this site that kind of talks about programming, but not really.

Maybe you should log in even to see the questions?

Comment: not an answer, but why 'nofollow', and not a regular robots.txt ?

Comment: Stop trying to turn it into a real SO question ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not want this.  I like being able to Google meta, and some discussion (maybe `always-friday-in-iceland`) are google-worthy on their own.

Answer (score 3):

If you search google for something program related my guess is that it would only turn up results for SO. I don't see how a google search from a normal question would turn a user up here especially since nothing really programing related is even discussed.

If somehow they end up here, it would be my guess that it is what they were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

There could be a link to SO itself. But is it very likely that Google would rank Meta-SO posts higher that SO posts, if someone googles for an answer?